# Flink 1.15.1 Checkpoint Problem with gRPC

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to understand the Flink Checkpointing system (in PyFlink). This is why I created a playground for it. Here is my environment

```python
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
config = Configuration(j_configuration=get_j_env_configuration(env._j_stream_execution_environment))
config.set_integer("python.fn-execution.bundle.size", 1000)
env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
env.enable_checkpointing(3000)
env.get_checkpoint_config().set_checkpointing_mode(CheckpointingMode.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
env.get_checkpoint_config().set_checkpoint_storage(FileSystemCheckpointStorage('file:///home/ubuntu/checkpoints'))
env.get_checkpoint_config().set_fail_on_checkpointing_errors(True)
env.get_checkpoint_config().set_tolerable_checkpoint_failure_number(1)
```

and I use state with a simple map function as

```python
class RandomRaiserMap(MapFunction):
    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        state_desc = ValueStateDescriptor('cnt', Types.INT())
        self.cnt_state = runtime_context.get_state(state_desc)

    def map(self, value: Row):
        cnt = self.cnt_state.value()
        self.cnt_state.update(1 if cnt is None else cnt + 1)
        if random.random() < 0.001:
            raise Exception("Planted")
        return Row(count=self.cnt_state.value(), **value.as_dict())
```

I used Kafka source (FlinkKafkaConsumer) as

```python
deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder() \
        .type_info(Types.ROW_NAMED(["seq", "payload", "event_time"], [Types.INT(), Types.STRING(), Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP()])).build()

    source = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test_checkpoint_sequence_2',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'}
    )
```

Now, when start to execute job,

```
3> +I[1,273328,23fe377010c55a18,2022-08-02 12:36:50.325000]
3> +I[2,273329,79782a6af4a9badb,2022-08-02 12:36:50.336000]
3> +I[3,273330,d3537b0b9aedf6f9,2022-08-02 12:36:50.348000]
3> +I[4,273331,d600824835e4f04d,2022-08-02 12:36:50.359000]
3> +I[5,273332,e1e0851bfbe743ab,2022-08-02 12:36:50.370000]
3> +I[6,273333,27a547b6d4469ac0,2022-08-02 12:36:50.381000]
3> +I[7,273334,f12da6dbccbfc1be,2022-08-02 12:36:50.392000]


Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 598, in <lambda>
    target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator),
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 581, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 426, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
    details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:38775 {grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up", grpc_status:1, created_time:"2022-08-02T12:36:53.274140888+00:00"}"
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 470, in input_elements
    element = received.get(timeout=1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/queue.py", line 178, in get
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 289, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 362, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 606, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 644, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 988, in process_bundle
    for element in data_channel.input_elements(instruction_id,
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 473, in input_elements
    raise RuntimeError('Channel closed prematurely.')
RuntimeError: Channel closed prematurely.

3> +I[188,273515,0fec22df999f7054,2022-08-02 12:36:52.362000]
3> +I[189,273516,9587bc4039b1b8d9,2022-08-02 12:36:52.373000]
3> +I[190,273517,e8e2d9dceb66ba15,2022-08-02 12:36:52.384000]
3> +I[191,273518,569c5513e994fa6b,2022-08-02 12:36:52.395000]
3> +I[192,273519,1f2809cd273204f9,2022-08-02 12:36:52.406000]
3> +I[193,273520,2f63560bdbeb2c96,2022-08-02 12:36:52.417000]
```

When a periodical checkpoint starts, I get this error. However, it manages to write a checkpoint on the given path (like `1f488f8d38f82d55cc342e1d0f676707`) and if an error happens, it can recover as well. I am stuck with what the error can be.

I use

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Java 11
- Python 3.8
- Flink 1.15.1
- apache-flink 1.15.1

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to identify the source of this issue ? I''m facing the same and can't seem to understand why. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a problem with the previous checkpoint. A fresh start (without the corresponding checkpoint folder) does not produce this error. I am not sure what is the problem there but I think Python UDF inside Java is not a stable feature yet. We end up not using Flink for that.